# Mongodb upsert into embedded array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Here is my document schema:

```
  var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      username: {type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true},
      email: {type:String, unique: true},
      currentSquads: [{seriesId: String, squad: [String]}]
});
```

Given a `_id`(for the UserSchema document), `seriesId` and `squad`: I would like to update the user document with the new squad if the seriesId already exists in the `currentSquads` array, otherwise add a new object in the `currentSquad` array.

What is the best way to do this in Mongoose?